# Firebase Cloud Functions Server Error. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND storage.googleapis.com

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am having an error in uploading simple functions on Firebase CF. Yesterday I can upload my commands on the server but now for some reason, I am not able to upload any functions even reuploading them. Below are the logs and error responses I get when uploading.

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (45.8 KB) for uploading
!  functions: Upload Error: Server Error. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND storage.googleapis.com storage.googleapis.com:443

Error: Server Error. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND storage.googleapis.com storage.googleapis.com:443



------------------------------------------FIREBASE-DEBUG--------------------------------------------

[debug] [2020-03-28T09:24:39.987Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] i  functions: packaged functions (45.8 KB) for uploading
[debug] [2020-03-28T09:24:40.171Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/coonna-a2ab5/locations/us-central1/functions:generateUploadUrl  

[debug] [2020-03-28T09:24:45.132Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2020-03-28T09:24:45.132Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-71f482e0-212a-4fd7-a2d2-
 <request body omitted>
[warn] !  functions: Upload Error: Server Error. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND storage.googleapis.com storage.googleapis.com:443
[debug] [2020-03-28T09:24:53.653Z] Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND storage.googleapis.com storage.googleapis.com:443
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
[error] 
[error] Error: Server Error. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND storage.googleapis.com storage.googleapis.com:443
```

Comment: This just looks like a temporary error with DNS resolution. Keep trying.  Reboot your machine if that might help clear some invalid cache.

Comment: Hello @DougStevenson. I tried to create a new account in another PC to check if the problem was in my PC but I got the same error. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: The same problem in Bangladesh also! Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919513/flutter-pub-get-cant-get-dependency-plugins-on-windows/60923417#60923417