# HTTP host "https://pub.dev/" is not reachable

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

> X HTTP host "https://pub.dev/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: The
> semaphore timeout period has expired.

[HTTP error Flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj3al.png)

I tried flutter doctor

Comment: have you see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/60919513/12838877   ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1. Disable firewalls and anti-virus
Step 2. Perform a clean boot
Step 3. Convert FAT32 to NTFS